# How to interpret « au hasard de »? And how do you paraphrase this locution?

Tags: sens

> ... s'il n’avait pas découvert cet objet ***au hasard de*** ses recherches.

The locution « au hasard » is about "randomness" while the locution « par hasard » is about "unintentionally, by chance".

But I wonder if « au hasard de ... » has the meaning of "unintentionally, by chance (during his researches)", and is therefore closer in meaning to « par hasard » than to « au hasard » ?

Comment: You got it right, it's closer to "par hasard" than "au hasard"

Comment: « Sur le parcours peu linéaire de ses recherches » ? C'est-à-dire, non *par hasard* comme s'il ne cherchait point faire des découvertes, mais pour souligner l'aspect imprévisible des résultats ?

Comment: Could we use [*par sérendipité*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rendipit%C3%A9) in this context?

Comment: Locution is not right. This is called a phrase in English. Locution is how people speak. au hazard de means randomly.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Perhaps « au hasard de ses recherches » is a shorter version of « par hasard au cours de ses recherches »?

Comment: Il y a une contradiction entre *hasard* et *recherche*.   *... au hasard de ses promenades ...* fait indubitablement référence à l'aléatoire car les promenades n'ont pas de but *a priori*. Or quand on fait de la recherche, on cherche. Du coup, le sens du mot *hasard* devient plus incertain. Son sens précis dépendra du contexte.

Comment: @jcm69 Pour rappel, la radioactivité a été découverte par hasard par les époux Curie lors de recherche sur les rayons X, dans ce cas: "Nos connaissance sur le radium seraient bien moindre si les époux Curie ne l'avaient pas découvert _au hasard de_ leurs recherches sur les rayons X" est un exemple tout a fait direct je pense.

Comment: @Mistalis I'd say yes, "par serendipité" has the exact meaning of "au hasard de recherches".

Comment: @jcm69 j'ai la sensation que je vous ai froissé, ce n'était pas le but,' pour illustration' aurait probablement été moins connoté 'leçon', mes excuses

Comment: Je voulais, humblement, dire que *par hasard* me semblait plus rugueux. *Par hasard* sera utilisé par les gens qui veulent insister sur le coté aléatoire, possiblement en mal ("Pfff il a trouvé ça par hasard"). *au hasard de leurs recherches* me semble plus doux et avoir dans la phrase une connotation de durée, de flânerie qui diminue l'aléatoire. Mais bon...

Comment: Ça serait très bien dans une réponse ça @jcm :)

Comment: @Tensibai je ne suis pas un grammairien juste un lecteur. Merci pour vos remarques. J'espère.

Comment: @Mistalis the expression ** Par sérendipité** could be equivalent but it seems awkward to replace an expression that most of french speakers understand by another one than less than 1% might understand.

Comment: @LaurentPELE Tout dépend du contexte, et du public visé. Si c'est pour écrire un livre, dans un langage soutenu, ça me semble bien plus adapté.

Comment: Au contraire, les puristes éviteront un tel anglicisme

Answer (score 1):

... s'il n’avait pas découvert cet objet **par hasard, à l'occasion de ses recherches**

So what you thought was right

Comment: Lorsque l'on créé une réponse reprenant une partie d'un commentaire déjà existant, il serait de bon ton d'étendre un peu la réponse en explicitant la raison. Cette réponse est même moins complète que le commentaire d'Alone-zee d'hier...

Comment: Euh, je n'avais pas vu le commentaire de Alone-zee. De toutes façons, je ne vois pas très bien ce qu'il y aurait en commun dans son commentaire avec ma réponse et qui ne serait pas déjà dans la question.

Comment: Je le copie: " Perhaps « au hasard de ses recherches » is a shorter version of *« par hasard au cours de ses recherches »* ?" <- au cours / à l'occasion c'est tout de même quasi identique, son commentaire à l'avantage de dire que c'est une forme raccourcie (de le supposer pour être exact). En écrivant cette réponse, formuler exactement cette idée de contraction serait bien je pense.

Comment: Ma réponse étant plus intuitive que réfléchie, je ne me suis pas senti obligé de fournir d'explications.

Comment: Il n'est jamais trop tard pour faire un [edit] et compléter, si ?

Comment: Je n'ai pas suffisamment de réputation pour ajouter des commentaires aux questions. Cependant, pour moi le principe de Stack exchange est de voir quelle est la meilleure réponse selon les votes des utilisateurs, pas de lire tous les commentaires.

Comment: Le principe est également de voter quand une réponse est utile, une réponse sans contexte ne l'est pas vraiment...

Comment: Tout à fait, mais ici, le contexte est bien exposé dans la question.

Comment: [How to write a good answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)